# Git Push Folder that was cloned from another site

Tags: git, drupal, git-push, git-clone

Hi so I have a folder root, that has its own `.git` file in root, that pushes to my repository. This works when I `git push`, but it omits the sub-folder `bootstrap` that I have cloned from another site. I have tried to set the folder's remote to my repo, but to no avail `git remote set-url origin MYURL`. I was wondering if anyone knows the steps

```
root:
    .git
    bootstrap/
        .git <-- points to Drupal's repo
```

Comment: Add the other repo as a submodule. You should be able to find plenty of tutorials on how to do so online.

Comment: @sakurashinken Thanks for the suggestion! I read on [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/803746#submodules) how to do submodules, but if I am understanding correctly, submodules keep the git repo of the third party, but in my case I don't want to keep it; should I just remove .git folder after a git clone?

Comment: Removing the third party repo git folder would make sense to me if you don’t want it.

Comment: If you are actually using third party libraries, you may want to look at a package manager to install your code. Honestly, I would just leave the other git repo, unless you have a reason to start making commits on the other branch. A submodule will not actually be committed in your code, it will only store a pointer to the commit that you cloned when you last committed the submodule.

Comment: You can check if there is a `.gitignore file` somewhere in the root folder, most times, third party folders come with that file. If you find it, check what is inside